# Android authentication using fingerprint

Tags: mobile, login

The flow of my applicaiton:

[1 -Login] -> [2 - Approve biometric use] -> [3 - Dashboard]

At the 2nd step, a user is authenticated and technically is inside of the app, enabling biometric. At this point, the user can click back button, Android standard keyboard. Is there an established pattern what should happen next?

My thoughts are the user should go back to [1 -Login] step with user name prefilled but password missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not really sure what you are trying to achieve there but the regular action would be to nothing happening if user presses the Back button and on double tapping the back button have a confirmation message asking to exit the app. If a user logged in he wouldn't like to log out just because he pressed back.

Answer (score 0):

Do I correctly understand your flow?

login --> biometric credentials --> dashboard

**On Dashboard**

Option 1

Option 2

Back Button --> logged out

Option 4

If so, the common way after a log out is to be at a login oder start screen. But you shouldnt use a back button for that. A common pattern is "Sign Out" or "Log Out" text or an icon based button like this [image].

Answer (score 0):

Once authenticated and at the "top-level" of the application, pressing back should back out of the app. Doing anything other than that would be strange.

I wouldn't logout a User for simply backing out of the app, that is effectively punishing the user. That would also make it ambiguous as to the authenticated state when backgrounding the app.

In terms of biometric authentication, you may be better off requiring that at the OS level and with a lockscreen - i.e. your app requires a certain level of security controls to be in use by the OS in order to be used, rather than the app itself requiring such hurdles just to enter the app. After all, mobile phones are personal devices and sessions plus logout were really invented for non-personal desktop computer scenarios (kiosks, Internet Cafes) and insecure communication channels. These decisions do depend on the risks associated with your app and business of course.